How to get the Lektor command working outside venv?
According to installation, Lektor needs to be installed in an virtual environment, but why and is there an workaround to get the lektor command working when its installed in system context?
Reason:
I need to deploy a website made with Lektor. The deployment process (Netlify) is automated and does not allow much configuration. That means, everything inside the requirements.txt gets installed, but I can not enforce that it's in an venv..
